# Retrieving value from combo box selected item

Tags: c#

I am using Windows Application.I Put some data as direct values in combo box.I defined  var type to combo box.I put these combo box on form load.Now I want to retrieve the value of selected item on my button2_click event and I tried below code to retrieve it,but it giving me error of The name comboBox does not exist in current context.Can any one suggest me how to fix it.

```
namespace WinDataStore
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var daysOfWeek =
                new[] { "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"
                         };

            // Initialize combo box
             var comboBox = new ComboBox
            {
                DataSource = daysOfWeek,
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 140),
                Name = "comboBox",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(166, 21),
                DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
            };

            // Add the combo box to the form.
            this.Controls.Add(comboBox);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new instance of FolderBrowserDialog.
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            // A new folder button will display in FolderBrowserDialog.
            folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            //Show FolderBrowserDialog
            DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {
                //Show selected folder path in textbox1.
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;
                //Browsing start from root folder.
               Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!textBox1.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
            {
                if (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text).Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text))
                    {
                        //Add file in ListBox.
                        listBox1.Items.Add(file);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                  //  listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(“No files Found at location:{0}”, textBox1.Text));
                }
            }
            string s = (string)comboBox.SelectedItem;
            listBox1.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to make this code shorter by only showing the interesting parts.

Comment: Make comboBox as class member. Currently it resides only inside Form1 constructor which is why you are getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`comboBox` was local variable in `Form1` .ctor. You can't access it from another method

options:

1) access to the control by name

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = this.Controls["comboBox"] as ComboBox;
    ...
}
```

2) make it a private member of the form as controls normally are, if they are created in designer

```
ComboBox comboBox;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Initialize combo box
    comboBox = new ComboBox() {...};
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Combobox appears to be a local variable. Try to make it a global field variable and you should be able to access it.